# Setting up Visual Studio 2015 - An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in dnx.host.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dnx

My Error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in dnx.host.dll

Using Debugger of Visual Studio 2015

My Code: Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace Hello_World
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Project.json:

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Hello World Console Application",
  "authors": [ "MNaples" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
  },

  "commands": {
    "Hello_World": "Hello_World"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the next step to get Visual studio to run my first program?
Thanks!

Windows 7 machine

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKXyC.jpg)

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you see any errors in the references? Also do you see any stacktrace/ inner exception details?

Comment: Windows 7, no errors in the Ref that I see

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267784/cannot-run-dnx-console-applications) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Project.json:

```
  "commands": {
"Hello_World": "run"  //not "Hello_World": "Hello World"
```

},

Thanks - Siva Gopal for pointing me to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267784/cannot-run-dnx-console-applications)